# Modify global variable from ajax request

Tags: javascript, json

I know this has been asked countless times, but i can't figure out the problem. As far as i know, you can modify global variables inside functions in javascript. It doesn't work for me.

```
var lastMessage = 0;
function loadChat() {
$.post("/lastmessage", { roomid: roomId })
    .done(function(data) {
        var response = JSON.parse(data);
        if (response.state == "success") {
            lastMessage = response.message;
            console.log("Inside: " + lastMessage);
        }
    });
}

console.log("Outside: " + lastMessage);
```

This gives me

```
Outside: 0
Inside: 17
```

The inside value is correct, the outside is not. What could the problem possibly be?

Comment: You may have noticed that the first log was printed after the second log, so `lastMessage` has indeed been modified but the second log has been executed before the ajax callback.. If you need to execute something based on the new value of `lastMessage`, you need to put that code where you're putting `log('Inside")`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's asynchronous, therefore when you call it from outside, it has not finished executing yet. What this means is that this part of your code is only reached once the post has completed

```
.done(function(data) {
        var response = JSON.parse(data);
        if (response.state == "success") {
            lastMessage = response.message;
            console.log("Inside: " + lastMessage);
        }
    });
```

but `console.log("Outside: " + lastMessage);` will continue executing without waiting, since post is asynchronous.

If you want something to happen after you retrieve the value you, one option would be to use a callback function, such as:

```
function printMessage(message) {
    console.log(message)
}

function loadChat(callback) {
$.post("/lastmessage", { roomid: roomId })
    .done(function(data) {
        var response = JSON.parse(data);
        if (response.state == "success") {
            lastMessage = response.message;
            callback(lastMessage);
        }
    });
}

loadChat(printMessage);
```